# Regex - Finding numbers in a certain String after a char and then editing them?

Tags: java, regex

I have multiple files in my directory, and the files contain a multiple String such as:

**Details: 0 5453 293**

**Details: 1 4223 123**

**Details: 2 8885 231**

The problem is that since I have multiple files, each file has different details with different numbers.

How would I replace all the numbers after the 0, 1, and 2?

I can't do:

.replace("Details: 0 5453 293", "Details: 0");

since I do not know what numbers there are after the 0 for other files.

Comment: You need to show your substantial current attempts to solve the problem with regex first and explain why they didn't meet your expectations.

Comment: Depending how consistent your data structure is, you might be able to get away with a simple `split()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **String.**`replaceAll` method with a regular expression to do this.

Using a Lookaround assertion:

```
String s = "Details: 2 8885 231";
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=^Details: \\d).*", "");
System.out.println(s); //=> "Details: 2"
```

Or using a capturing group:

```
String s = "Details: 2 8885 231";
s = s.replaceAll("^(Details: \\d).*", "$1");
System.out.println(s); //=> "Details: 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to eliminate all the 4 and 3 digits numbers

**sample:**

```
String s = "Details: 0 5453 293";
s = s.replaceAll("[0-9][0-9][0-9]+", "");

System.out.println(s);
```

**result:**

```
Details: 0
```